# Spring Nested object is getting null while submitting form

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf, spring-form

I am trying to post data with thymeleaf, command model has two nested objects, one is fetching data, while another is fetching null. I am confused, what is going on behind the scene, though using the same concept and code.

Please notice, I am getting data for People Object in logs, but not for Project Object, though using the same code. Please help.

Form Snippet.

```
<form th:fragment="form" method="post" th:object="${expense}" th:action="@{/createexpense}">

<input type="hidden" th:field="*{expenseId}" />
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textarea">Expense Description</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">                     
    <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" th:field="*{description}" name="textarea">Expense Description</textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Amount</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Enter Amount" th:field="*{amount}" class="form-control input-md"> 
 </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Project</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <select class="form-control" id="sel1" th:field="*{project}">
    <option th:each="project: ${projects}" th:value="${{project.projectId}}" th:text="${project.name}">1</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">People</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <select class="form-control" id="sel1" th:field="*{people}" >
   <option th:each="people: ${peoples}" th:value="${people.id}" th:text="${people.name}">1</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Expense Type</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">

  <select class="form-control" id="sel1" th:field="*{expenseType}">
    <option th:each="exp:  ${expenseTypes}" th:value="${exp}" th:text="${exp}">1</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Create 
Expense</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn- danger" value="Submit"/
 </div>
</div>
```

Model Bean Class

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"},
        allowGetters = true)
@Entity
public class Expense {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long expenseId;

    @Lob
    private String description;

    @OneToOne
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private People people;

    private Double amount;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedAt;


    @ManyToOne
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private Project project;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ExpenseType expenseType;

    public Expense(String description, Double expense) {
        this.description = description;
        this.amount = expense;
    }

    public Expense() {
    }


    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = new Date();
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void setUpdatedAt() {
        this.updatedAt = new Date();
    }

}
```

Controller Snippet

```
@PostMapping(path="/createexpense")
    public Expense addExpense(@ModelAttribute("expense") Expense expense ,BindingResult result){

    log.debug(expense.toString());
    expense.setPeople(peopleService.getPeople(expense.getPeople().getId()));
    expense.setProject(flatProjectService.getFlatProjectById(expense.getProject().getProjectId()));
    return expenseService.createExpense(expense);
}

@GetMapping(path="/createexpense")
public ModelAndView addExpense(ModelAndView modal){
    //adding projects list and people list in expense view
    modal.addObject("projects", flatProjectService.getAllProjects());
    modal.addObject("peoples", peopleService.getAllPeoples());
    modal.setViewName("createexpense");
    modal.addObject("expense", new Expense());
    modal.addObject("expenseTypes", ExpenseType.values());
    return modal;
}
```

Error Logs

```
2018-07-22 18:22:44.010 DEBUG 25500 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.d.b.controller.HomeController          : Expense(expenseId=null, description=hello, people=People(id=2, name=Avinash, peopleType=null, phoneNo=9504974665, address=Beside Maa Clinic, expense=[], createdDate=2009-06-01 13:45:30.0, updatedDate=2009-06-01 13:45:30.0), amount=5000.0, createdAt=null, updatedAt=null, project=null, expenseType=PAID)
2018-07-22 18:22:44.090 ERROR 25500 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

Comment: can you add how you are doing ajax call..  See in Console what JSON is being Send in POST call

Comment: I am not using ajax, though this is what sending to the controller; `expenseId=&description=hello&amount=7000&project=2&people=2&expenseType=PAID&textinput=`

Comment: You are passing people as 2 but in Controller you have written expense.getPeople().getId().  which will not work.  So your POST call format will not match with your Expense Object

Comment: People object is parsed perfectly, you can see in the logs, Ashish, but the problem is why Project object is not parsed. Is there any other way of doing this ?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the exception and indicate matching lines from the stack trace and the code you posted.

Comment: Ok. One last thing..  When your HTMl is loaded..  Can you see Data in Project select Combo.  Can you inspect and see what is data from value and text for option field

Comment: While fetching from GET request, All Project and Peoples data is visible in dropdown list. Problems only comes, when I try to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your HTML logic. I suspect issue is in Project Loop

You are defining `th:field="*{project}"`
but using as `pro` in option

Ideally it should be like this

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Project</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <select class="form-control" id="sel1" th:field="*{project}">
    <option th:each="project: ${projects}" th:value="${project.projectId}" 
   th:text="${pro.name}">1</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried, with no luck.

Comment: There is some issue in logic how you are sending showing data in HTML or sending Data .  Not in backend...

Comment: Ashish, I have edited my question, the whole form is posted now.

Comment: Hey for project th you have th:value="${{project.projectId}}"   shouldnt it be  th:value="${project.projectId}"   single curley braces

Comment: Tried, but issue did not resolve. I have added a field projectId, thus proceed with the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Ashish for your cooperation.